# Wrong number of type arguments for Function9, should be 10

Tags: scala

I am trying to make a companion object for class TaxiRide to make be able to convert it to tuple.

```
object TaxiRide extends
  Function9[Long, Boolean, String, String, Float, Float, Float, Float, Short]
```

Now I am observing an error that looks self contradictory:

```
Wrong number of type arguments for Function9, should be 10
```

I am curious about why I get such an error and does the idea of converting case class object to tuple is reasonable.

Comment: Functions have a return type parameter too, so `Function9` has 10 type parameters (9+1).

Comment: Your function's too long bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like this:

```
object TaxiRide extends Function9[Long, Boolean, String, String, Float, Float, Float, Float, Short, TaxRide]
```

Please note the last type parameter `TaxRide` for the return value.

Answer (score 2):

If you inspect [Function9 api](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function9.html) there is an addition `+R` parameter which you need to pass to the function which is the return type i.e. `Tuple9`.

So your function should be defined as below

```
object TaxiRide extends Function9[Long, Boolean, String, String, Float, Float, Float, Float, Short, Tuple9[Long, Boolean, String, String, Float, Float, Float, Float, Short]]{
  override def apply(v1: Long, v2: Boolean, v3: String, v4: String, v5: Float, v6: Float, v7: Float, v8: Float, v9: Short): (Long, Boolean, String, String, Float, Float, Float, Float, Short) =
    (v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9)
}
```

So that if you pass 9 parameters matching the dataTypes to `TaxiRide`, it should return you `Tuple9`.

You can change the `returnType` according to your requiremnts i.e. `+R`